# Access denied error while running the simple web api .net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im getting below error while running the simple webapi in .net 6. One webapi is running but i can't create or run another webapi anywhere in the laptop. Not even after stopping the running api. All other projects giving same error.

[image: Access denied error]

Port are different for each project.
There is no right issue as I tried running with admin also.

Using command line for dotnet core

```
PS C:\Projects\demos> dotnet new webapi -n SecondService
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\Projects\demos\SecondService\SecondService.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Projects\demos\SecondService\SecondService.csproj (in 240 ms).
Restore succeeded.


PS C:\Projects\demos> cd .\SecondService\
PS C:\Projects\demos\SecondService> dotnet run
Building...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5097,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Projects\demos\SecondService\obj\D 
ebug\net6.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0\SecondService.exe". Access to the path 'C:\Projects\demos\SecondService\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied. 
 [C:\Projects\demos\SecondService\SecondService.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

PS C:\Projects\demos\SecondService>
```

Comment: Your executable, for whatever reason, is running. You should kill the process to be able to delete it or overwrite it.

Comment: I tried to restart the VS, VS Code and machine but no luck. Even if shutting down the machine did not kill the it, not sure how will it be killed.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes, its Windows. My bad, didn't mention the OS.